# Merge accidental hg heads?

Tags: mercurial

Please help me merge the heads that I didn't want in the first place:

```
    C:\Users\hg\>hg push
    pushing to https://usernm@bitbucket.org/zzz/yyy
    http authorization required
    realm: Bitbucket.org HTTP
    user: 
    password:
    searching for changes
    abort: push creates new remote head 841acfa3a36b!
    (merge or see "hg help push" for details about pushing new heads)

    C:\Users\hg\m>hg merge
    abort: uncommitted changes
    (use 'hg status' to list changes)

    C:\Users\hg\>

C:\Users\hg>hg commit -m " merge"
nothing changed (12 missing files, see 'hg status')

C:\Users\hg\>hg status
! montaoproject\common\__init__.pyc
! montaoproject\common\templatefilters.pyc
! montaoproject\conf\__init__.pyc
! montaoproject\conf\settings.pyc
! montaoproject\static\img\github.png
! montaoproject\static\img\index_in2.png
! montaoproject\static\img\openid.png
! montaoproject\static\pakistan-reg_files\wikimedia-button.png
! montaoproject\wtforms\ext\__init__.pyc
! montaoproject\wtforms\ext\appengine\__init__.pyc
! montaoproject\wtforms\ext\appengine\db.pyc
! montaoproject\wtforms\ext\appengine\fields.pyc
? .idea\.name
```

[image]

```
outstanding uncommitted changes in repository C:/Users/hg/, not merging with pulled head
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> abort: uncommitted changes

Tells you in clean English: you must commit before merge

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

hg push -f -r Number_Rev